# I'm confused by this. Won't the array contents stay the same?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What will be the contents of the a array after the following statements are executed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10


int main() {

int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int *p = &a[0], *q = &a[N - 1], temp;

while (p > q) 
{
    temp = *p;
    *p++ = *q;
    *q-- = temp;
}
printf("%d", a[N]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: nothing happens, because p is smaller than q.

Comment: What is the result if you execute this code and print the final contents of the a array?

Comment: Why don't you run this code and then print the array content ?

Comment: And if you use the statement `p < q, this should reverse the order of the array.

Comment: I thought that it might reverse the array but i ran it and tried to print out the results and it gave me a long strange negative string of numbers

Comment: i'm sorry if this seems elementary, im very new to programming

Comment: @Crowe How do you print the output? I ran this with my correction and it worked just fine. And your code should just not change anything at all. So your print should be okay.

Comment: `printf("%d", a[N]);` is wrong, there is no such thing as `a[N]`. This produces undefined behavior. Also change condition to `p<q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment nothing would happen, because `p` is smaller than `q`.

If you change your while loop to `while (p <= q)`, you would inverse the order of the array.

You take the first element(`p`) and put it in `temp`.

Then you put the last element (`q`) and put it in the first place (`p`).

Then you increment `p` so it points to the second element.

Afterwards you write `temp` in the last element. And decrease `q` so it points to the second to last element. Do this again until `p` is greater than  or same as `q`.

edit:
Your problem is with your print statement. You just print the element after the last element of the array by using `a[N]`. Your array is from `a[0]` to `a[9]`. By reading from `a[10]` you invoke undefined behavior, because it is not part of the array. So you get a random number.

You'll want something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i<N;i++) 
{
   printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,a[i]);
}
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#define N 10


int main() {

 int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
 int *p = &a[0], *q = &a[N - 1], temp;

 while (p > q) 
 {
  temp = *p;
  *p++ = *q;
  *q-- = temp;
 }
 printf("%d", a[N]);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Kazi Thank you so much. A lot of these comments seem to be condescending. I appreciate the help and the manner in which you did so. I am very new to programming and I'm trying to learn it all on my own.

Comment: Wrong answer! `p>=q` is not matched, at the beginning `p` is less than `q`. Should be `while (p<q)`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thank you for pointing out the mistake I made while I wanted to correct it....(see comments)

Answer (score 0):

As Mak said, provided the `while` condition is actually `p < q`, the code switches the first and the last values, then the second and the second to last, etc.

**Explanation**

The pointer `p` is set at the beginning at the array, and `q`, at the end. At every loop, the value at `p`, which is `*p`, is stored in `temp`, then the value at `q`, which is `*q`, is put at `p`, then `p` is incremented (ie, it moves by one step towards the end of the array). Then, the value in `temp` is put at `q`, and `q` is decremented (ie, it moves by one step towards the beginning of the array).

When `p` and `q` meet, the loop breaks.

Advice for the next time: print the array to know what it has become.